# What does wsl --import-in-place do?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Ostensibly, [`wsl --import-in-place <Distribution Name> <FileName>` is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands#import-a-distribution-in-place):

> Imports the specified .vhdx file as a new distribution. The virtual hard disk must be formatted in the ext4 filesystem type.

`wsl --import <Distribution Name> <InstallLocation> <FileName> --vhd` can already do that—the only difference I see is `--import` requires a `<InstallLocation>`.

What does `wsl --import-in-place` do (differently from `--import`)?

Comment: It allows you to use a vhdx file from say a Hyper-V VM and use it for a WSL instance.  The description of the command, "Imports the specified .vhdx file as a new distribution.", clearly indicates the only requirement is that the virtual hdd must be formatted as ext4. `wsl --import` exist primaryly to import .tar files and WSL1 instances.

Comment: @Ramhound Let me see if I'm understanding you correctly. `--import` is supposed to accept the output of `--export`; `--import-in-place` accepts non-WSL Virtual Machines (too?)?

Comment: The documentation says it does provided its formatted as EXT4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a distro, WSL copies the drive to `InstallLocation/ext4.vhdx`. This might cause conflicts
if this file already exists.

To avoid collisions, using `import-in-place` creates a
new distro that will not conflict on the disk
with any existing one.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, it's effectively `--import` but it 1) *only* accepts vhdx files and 2) sets `<InstallLocation>` for you?

Comment: Yes, it makes for a simpler interface and perhaps a unified storage scheme for all distributions. The specs say only for vhdx with ext4.